# How to get a list of all the image processing functions in Mathematica 10.4

Tags: image-processing, built-in-symbols

Could someone kindly guide me as to how to get all the image processing functions (segmentation, analysis, morphological operations etc... ) for 2D and 3D images in Mathematica including ones that do not begin with word "Image"

Comment: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ImageProcessing.html

Comment: i am aware of that. I was thinking if there is a way to get a list of functions within the notebook.

Comment: `WolframLanguageData[EntityClass["WolframLanguageSymbol", {"FunctionalityArea", "ImageSymbols"}]]` gives a partial list.

Comment: @J.M. that should be one answer. It gives a longer list than the current answer, but doesn't include `{BilateralFilter, ColorConvert, ColorQuantize, ColorReplace, EntropyFilter, ExampleData, GaussianFilter, GradientFilter, 
HistogramTransform, ImageHistogram, ImageIdentify, ImageInstanceQ, 
Import, MeanShiftFilter, Rasterize, TotalVariationFilter}`, as these are considered "ColorSymbols", "FileSystemSymbols", "GraphicsSymbols", 
"HistogramSymbols", "ImageFilterSymbols", "MachineLearningSymbols", or
"PacletSymbols"

Comment: @Karsten, I got lazy trying to find the other symbol types (the docs were not very helpful in that regard); if you want, you can write an answer of your own, since you have the complete list.

Comment: @J.M. That's not a complete list, but just the complement of your list with Bob's. Not going to answer, as I already closed that nb without saving. Moreover `Entity`s are annoying and annoyingly slow.

Answer (score 7):

**EDIT:** Added [`Union`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Union.html) to sort and eliminate duplicates. Displayed results as table with [`Grid`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Grid.html)

```
base = "https://reference.wolfram.com/language";

len = StringLength[base <> "/ref/"];

funcs = StringTake[#, {len + 1 ;; -6}] & /@
       Select[
        Import[
         base <> "/guide/ImageProcessing.html",
         "Hyperlinks"],
        StringTake[#, len] === base <> "/ref/" &] //
      Flatten // 
     ToExpression // Union // Quiet;

funcs // Partition[#, 20] & //
  Transpose // Grid[#, Alignment -> Left] &
```

[image]

Or more simply (provided by [Karsten 7.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/18476/karsten-7))

```
Multicolumn[funcs, 3]
```

**EDIT 2:**  For a more complete listing, scrape multiple guides related to image processing

```
guides = {
   "ImageProcessing",
   "BasicImageManipulation",
   "ImageFilteringAndNeighborhoodProcessing",
   "SegmentationAnalysis",
   "ImageRestoration",
   "ImageGeometry",
   "MathematicalMorphology",
   "ComputerVision",
   "3DImages",
   "RasterImageFormats",
   "ColorProcessing"
   };

guideHyperlinks =
  "http://reference.wolfram.com/" <>
     "language/guide/" <>
     # <> 
     ".html" & /@ guides;

base =
  "http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/";

hyperlinks = Select[
    Flatten[
      Import[#, "Hyperlinks"] & /@
       guideHyperlinks] //
     Union,
    StringTake[#,
       StringLength[base]] == base &] //
   Quiet;

funcs =
  StringTake[#, {StringLength[base] + 1, -6}] & /@
   hyperlinks;

Length[funcs]

(*  254  *)

Multicolumn[funcs, 3]

(* large output deleted *)
```

Comment: [`Multicolumn`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Multicolumn.html) is quite convenient here: `Multicolumn[funcs, 3]`

Answer (score 0):

This will give all of what you want

```
CanonicalName@*EntityList@
 Entity["WolframLanguageSymbol", {"FunctionalityAreas" -> 
    "ColorSymbols" | "ImageFilterSymbols" | "ImageSymbols"}]
```

> {AlphaChannel,BarcodeImage,<<262>>,ZoomFactor,$ImageFormattingWidth}

Comment: I don't think that `WordCloud`, `VectorColorFunction`, `ChromaticityPlot`, `ZoomCenter` and some other returned symbols should be considered as image-processing functions even in an extended sense. I also don't think that such symbols as `White`, `Hue` etc. should be included: they are *related* to image-processing functionality but all the language basics are related to this functionality in some sense (for example, `Blank`, `Pattern`, `Rule` etc.)! There is no point to include everything related into a list of image-processing functions.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I don't think too.But the Mr. Wolfram [think so](http://o8aucf9ny.bkt.clouddn.com/2016-08-08-18-46-51.png). :)